# MPC-HC lags hard when there are lots of subs on screen

Tags: subtitles, lag, media-player-classic

I've been watching various anime lately and I noticed that around generously decorated with subtitles opening and ending sequences, the CPU spikes, free buffered frames pool drains and severe lags appear, making the picture and, eventually, the sound tear. Disabling subtitles altogether makes for a perfectly smooth audiovisual experience on my rig, except I can no longer enjoy singing along without subtitles.

I've already tried modifying configuration to force DXVA video processing, but that doesn't seem to help, because the problem isn't in the video, but in subtitles, processing of whom relies on CPU, not GPU.

Is there a way I can speed up subtitle processing in Media Player Classic to avoid lags and tearing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try installing [the xy-VSFilter subtitle filter](https://code.google.com/p/xy-vsfilter/).

Certain fansub groups have been pushing for more high quality releases using using madVR, LAV Filters, MPC-HC and xy-VSFilter. This might be one of the side effect of the change.